# Getting Bearer null in vue3 response

Tags: axios, request, response, vuejs3

I am posting data with axios and I want the authorization token from the header of the response.

```js
     await axios.post('authenticate', {
        params: {
          one: this.one,
          two: this.two,
        },
      }).then((res) => { console.log(res.config.headers.authorization); }); # returns Bearer null
```

I am getting an Options and a Post response when I look at the Network Tab and the post request has the Bearer value in the Response Headers and "Bearer null" in the Request Headers. I am apparently only getting the Request Headers from `res` and I cant figure out how to get the Response headers authorization value. The `res.headers` has no Authorization attribute at all. Only this:

```
{
    "cache-control": "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate",
    "content-length": "0",
    "expires": "0",
    "pragma": "no-cache"
}
```

How do I access the Authorization value of the Response Headers?

Answer (score 0):

The response headers are stored in `headers` (not `config.headers`, which are the headers from the request configuration).

Assuming the response actually contains the `Authorization` header, it could be accessed via `res.headers.Authorization`:

```js
axios.post('authenticate', {
  params: { /*...*/ },
}).then((res) => {
  console.log(res.headers.Authorization)
})
```

But as you pointed out, `res.headers` does not contain that header, so the backend isn't populating it.